# Why a function $f$ smaller than $g$ can have integral same as $g$?

Tags: calculus

In Apostol Book, on the topic of fundamental theorem of calculus he mentioned that $$|f(t)-f(x)|<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon  \implies \int_{x}^{x+h}|f(t)-f(x)| \mathrm{ d}x \leq \int_{x}^{x+h}\frac{1}{2}\epsilon \mathrm{d}x$$ 
Shouldn't there be a $<$ sign instead of $\leq$.
Here $t$ is variable and $x$ is fixed.

Comment: What's wrong with a $\leq$ sign?  We aren't losing a great deal by weakening the inequality for $h>0$, and for $h=0$ we need that equality.

Comment: But here we are proving a limit and we don't care about $h=0$

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $4<5$ is true. Thus $4\le5$ is also true. It really doesn't matter if you add an equality, the statement is still true so everything is all good.

Furthermore, according to what you said "we're taking limits so we don't care about $h=0$. By the same token, we're taking limits so we don't care even if they could be equal.